# Controlar el timming en llamadas a funciones ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo una función en javascript en una pagina, que consulta un dato a través del controller.. que luego va a la BD.. etc..
el tema, es que la función en javascript, que es llamada en el evento $(document).ready(function (), no me retorna nada.. o en realidad me retorna undefines. investigando un poco sobre el tema, me di cuenta que la  llamada ajax que esta dentro de la función, se demora en traer el resultado.. es decir, la pagina no la espera (obvio, porque es ajax) y cuando necesita procesar el resultado, solo tiene el valor undefined.
Leí por ahí, que hay que consultar por un readystatus == 4. pero estoy medio perdido en esto.. precisamente, donde debo consultar esto? cuando hago la llamada a la función??, o en la función?.
El código es el siguiente:

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // si llega aca, significa que el profesional tiene alñ menos 1 turno.

            var IdProfesional = 0;
            var turnoSelecc = fnObtieneTurnos(IdProfesional);
            alert("turnoSelecc = " + turnoSelecc);
          
            // aca va el resto de la funcion que usa el valor  turnoSelecc y que llega con 
            // undefined

        });

  
  // esta es la funcion que tiene la llamada ajax
   <script type="text/javascript">
        //Busca los turnos disponibles para el profesional y los despliega en pantalla
        function fnObtieneTurnos(IdProfesional) {
            var turnoSeleccionado = 0;
            var parametrosAjax = {
                "IdProfesional": IdProfesional
            };
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(parametrosAjax),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/Selecciona/GetTurnos',
                    success: function (turnos) {
                        if (turnos.length > 0) {
                            if (turnos.length > 1) {
                                var comboTurnos = "<select>";
                                $.each(turnos, function (idx, turno) {
                                    comboTurnos += "<option value='" + turno.Value + "'>" + turno.Text + "</option>";
                                });
                                comboTurnos += "</select>";
                                $("#turnosDiv").append(comboTurnos);
                                // aca retornamos el primer elemento
                                turnoSeleccionado = turnos[0].Value;
                            }
                            else {
                                // aca hay un solo turno
                                var comboTurnos = "";
                                $.each(turnos, function (idx, turno) {
                                    comboTurnos = turno.Text;
                                });
                                $("#turnosDiv").append(comboTurnos);
                                turnoSeleccionado = turnos[0].Value;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            var msgNoHayTurnos = "No se turnos disponibles para este usuario";
                            $('#turnosProf').html(msgNoHayTurnos);
                            turnoSeleccionado = 0;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        var msgNoHayTurnos = "No se turnos disponibles para este usuario";
                        $('#turnosProf').html(msgNoHayTurnos);
                        turnoSeleccionado = 0;
                    }
                });
            return turnoSeleccionado;
        }
    </script>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega a tu ajax el parámetro `async : false`. Esto hará que tu tarea no se asíncrona, por lo tanto tendrá que esperar tener resultados (de éxito o de error) y seguir con el curso del código.

Es dentro de tu función que ejecuta el ajax donde asignas los valores, por lo tanto es obvio que si la tarea esta trabajando en segundo plano, te mostrara los valores que tu mencionas.

Comment: maestro, funciono muy bien tu sugerencia. te agradezco mucho la ayuda. Saludos