# Problema al retornar respuesta de función con ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

tengo la siguiente situación, en una aplicación estoy llamando una función, que me trae un formulario, al enviar el formulario yo llamo otra función que ya tengo para realizar una validación, el problema es que la función no me esta retornando nada, como es un proyecto de la empresa no puedo facilitar código ya que igual es extenso, pero realice un código similar que muestra lo que estoy realizando:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="formulario">/div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    formulario();
});
function formulario(){
  $('#formulario').html('<form id="consultar" method="post" > <input id ="respuesta" type="text"> <button>Enviar</button> </form>');
  $("#consultar").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var resultado_cons = fechas (1,2, 1);
     $('#respuesta').val(resultado_cons);
  });

}
function fechas (per,ayo, tip){
        $.ajax({
      url: "consulta.php",
    }).done(function() {
      return "Yes";
    });

}
```

La función se ejecuta sin problemas y la respuesta de la función fechas me trae la respuesta sin problemas, lo que no entiendo es que en la variable resultado_cons  de la función formulario, no me guarda ningun valor y la variable queda como undefined, no se si con estos fragmentos de código me puedan ayudar, de ate mano Gracias por revisar.

Comment: El problema es por que AJAX es asíncrono, y cuando tú le asignas un valor a tu variable `resultado_cons` la función no ha terminado de ejecutarse por lo que tu variable queda como indefinida, y por ende la siguiente línea donde se la asignas como valor a tu id `#respuesta` no te arroja nada

Comment: Prueba en el `.done()` agregar la siguiente asignación `var resultado_ cons = resp` donde resp es la respuesta de la función callback de AJAX, y seguido de esto `$('#respuesta').val(resultado_cons)`

Comment: Gracias por contestar, @Lixus Gracias por recordarme ese detalle, no había caído en cuenta en eso, creo que ya se por que dirección investigar, si doy con la respuesta la publicare, sino de igual forma lo comentare, nuevamente Gracias

Comment: Sobre lo del var resultado_ cons = resp tambien lo intente y tampoco funciono, buscando encontre desactivarle el asincronico con async   : false, pero tampoco funciono jajjaja, creo q me tocara volver a hacer el contenido de la funcion fechas dentro de la función formulario que era lo que no queria xD

Comment: ¿pero si cambiaste esta línea de esta forma? `.done(function(resp){...}))`

Comment: si ya la cambie y siguió igual :/

Answer (score 1):

Tal como conteste en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77261/controlar-el-timming-en-llamadas-a-funciones-ajax/77263#77263) respuesta, para solucionar ese problema debes agregar a tu funcion ajax el parametro `async : false`, de modo que la llamada al ajax no sea asincrona y se ejecute tal como tu quieres.

Lo otro que te recomiendo, es utilizar las funciones de `success` y `error` en la llamada al ajax para verificar porque falla

```
$.ajax({
    async : false,
    url: '',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log()
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Comment: Ya lo probé y no me funciono.

Comment: actualice mi respuesta @Andrés, si no funciona es porque tu ajax probablemente este dando errores.

Comment: Lo siento pero no funciona, y el ajax esta bn ya que se ejecuta de manera correcta y en la consola no se marca ningun tipo de error, al final me toco ejecutar la función y almacenar la respuesta para posteriormente realizar la validación, de igual forma Gracias.